# how to display current colour values of pixel under cursor in gimp?

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to display the colour values of a pixel currently under the cursor?

I've seen that in different other software. Why do I need that? I have to clone textured areas in a picture. But those textured areas vary greatly in brightness. It ist not possible to select an area to clone with a matching brightness with bare eyes.

So I'd like to see the current colour values in the status bar, if possible. How do I activate that? I tried to find it in the documentation, but I do not know, what terms to search for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd like to see the color value updated too... at the moment I'm using the [Pointer Dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pointer-info-dialog.html), which is updated while moving the mouse and shows the numerical values under the cursor:

[image: Pointer Dialog]

You can show it using *Windows... Dockable dialogs... Pointer*

Answer (score 1):

The [`Pointer` dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pointer-info-dialog.html) will show you in real time the RGBA/HSVA/CYMKA components (for a layer or "merged") of the pixels under the pointer, for the active layer or for the composite image (`Sample merged` option).

[image]

The [`Sample points` dialog](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-sample-point-dialog.html) will show you in real time the RGBA/HSVA/CYMKA components (for a layer or "merged") of up to four points you can position on the image.

Comment: Not the question that was asked. This method requires selection of points. What the OP wants, and I want is to move the cursor around and see the RGB value of whatever I'm pointing at,

Comment: @BerndWechner Use the Pointer dialog, see augmented answer